# DLL criada em c# fixada na pasta principal

Tags: c#, dll

Estou aprendendo a desenvolver DLLs em C#, utilizando o UnmanagedExports para ser exportada para outra linguagem (Clarion)

A DLL funciona, mas com uma exceção: o aplicativo só "enxerga" a DLL na pasta principal "C:\" e não na pasta corrente. Reparei que dentro do arquivo da DLL consta "\arquivo.dll".

Como resolver este problema?

Comment: Não encontrei nenhuma documentação online do Clarion. Para resolver o problema você tem que alterar a pasta onde o aplicativo está sendo corrido, no caso, ele está procurando a DLL no `root_path` (C:\) e não na pasta corrente.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido !

Para quem conhece a linguagem Clarion, o problema está no libmaker.exe. Baixei uma versão "corrigida" e a DLL funcionou.

Agradeço a todos !